# Android Studio navigation xml file can't type keyboard keys

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-navigation

MacOS

Android studio version 4.1.1

Navigation:

```
'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
```

Inside the `navigation.xml` file in `split/design` screen when adding a `New Destination` typing the letter 'e' in the `searchbox` doesn't add it but instead it pops out an `Issues` window.

Also when pressing 'o' the screens rotate to landscape mode.

I know this is not a huge deal and I found a workaround but would be great to solve it somehow.

Comment: i think it also randomly doesn't pick up the letter `r` as well

Answer (score 0):

While in the `split/design` screen, Android Studio catches your input as keyboard shortcuts. You can either remap/completely delete chosen keys or type only in `code` screen.
For more info on key mappings in `design` screen and how to change them, see
[Keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)

We can see from the shortcuts docs that the letters(keys)

Toggle between Design and Blueprint modes   B

Toggle between Portrait and Landscape modes O

Toggle devices  D

Force refresh   R

Toggle render errors panel  E

Will generate problems when typing in the `split/design` screen

UPDATE 28.01.2021

on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 4 it seems that in `split/design` screen you can type without any shortcut catches as long as you are focused on the `code` part. If you change  your focus on `design`, shortcuts are working again

Comment: `Android Studio catches your input as keyboard shortcuts` i consider this a bug honestly

Comment: Yeah. It worked fine when we had only `code` and `design` screens, but it doesn't work so good in the `split/design` screen which was added sometime later